# How to stop an Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks

The problem starts when I want to send a "take picture intent".
On htc one+ (the phone I test my applications on) it seems that this intent is too heavy for my application that it calls onTrimMemory method (the method that is apparently called when your app is consuming too much memory and is about to stop) and then the app stops.
So I decided to call the cancel() method on the AsyncTask that handles the Intent. But what to do next? 
Here is the relevant snippet:

```
 private class djford extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            while(1>0){
                if(isCancelled()){
                    ***// WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE??***
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    if (level >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW) {
        fff.cancel(false);
        tv1.setText("canceled before stopping");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        }
        else {
            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(returnUri);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, you start by getting rid of the `AsyncTask`, as it is unnecessary (and the `while(1>0)` loop is simply evil). Start the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity. Get the results in `onActivityResult()`. Make sure you save relevant state using `onSaveInstanceState()`, to handle the case where your process is terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.

Comment: So do you know what I should do after overriding the onSaveInstanceState() ? @CommonsWare

Comment: Well, nothing. You get your results in `onActivityResult()`, and you use them. This flow does not change whether your process was terminated or not.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is exactly there. I call the onActivityRuslt() method but I'm still facing crash. That's because, apparently , when you run the startActivityForResult() your activity normally shouldn't stop. But in this case it does so when the users take pictures and want to come back to the application, home screen appears @CommonsWare

Comment: "I call the onActivityRuslt() method" -- *you* do not call `onActivityResult()`. The *framework* does, after the camera has taken a picture. "when the users take pictures and want to come back to the application, home screen appears" -- that's a bug in the camera app. There is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my post and added the onActivityResult() to make you sure that I have called this method. But as you said, this bug is no way solvable?! @CommonsWare

Comment: That camera app, when the user is done taking a picture, must be calling `startActivity()` to bring up the home screen. I do not know why, but this isn't the first time I have heard of this sort of bug. [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not very reliable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

Comment: So you're right. I did a test; I installed famous social networking applications on the same phone and tried to use the "take photo" feature. the result was the same; those apps crushed too. Thanks by the way @CommonWare